# Mysql group by and having & sum of one column from table one

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Currently I am running a sql script that gives result from two tables (cc_transactions and cc_transaction_status) with below query:

```
SELECT cc_transactions.transAmount as amt
FROM cc_transactions 
INNER JOIN cc_transaction_status ON cc_transactions.id = cc_transaction_status.transaction_id 
WHERE account_id = '11E5F26C8164C3BABF85F8B156B0DBF5'
GROUP BY cc_transactions.id 
HAVING MAX(cc_transaction_status.sortOrder) = 0
```

The result is

```
amt     
200.0000
300.0000
1000.0000
```

I want the result to be

```
amt     
1500.0000
```

Can anyone please look in to this.

Comment: Your query is malformed.  You have a column in the `SELECT` that is not in the `GROUP BY`.  Either fix the query or -- better yet -- provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. pls use below link to get the sql script(including structure and data) https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=!ABU-9-UFh7JABk0&cid=795A187E7EEA2A7F&id=795A187E7EEA2A7F!7875&parId=root&action=locate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(Amount.amt) from (
      SELECT cc_transactions.transAmount as amt
      FROM cc_transactions 
      INNER JOIN cc_transaction_status ON cc_transactions.id = cc_transaction_status.transaction_id 
      WHERE account_id = '11E5F26C8164C3BABF85F8B156B0DBF5'
      GROUP BY cc_transactions.id 
      HAVING MAX(cc_transaction_status.sortOrder) = 0
) as Amount;
```

If your query run successfully then it will give sum....

Comment: Thanks but that does't worked. gives Error Code: 1248
Every derived table must have its own alias. Pls use below link for sample scripts https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=!ABU-9-UFh7JABk0&cid=795A187E7EEA2A7F&id=795A187E7EEA2A7F!7875&parId=root&action=locate

Comment: @k10gaurav I have modified my query.. Try this one and tell me is it working or not?

Comment: You rocks man!! That's worked perfectly I was looking for.Thanks a ton!